# How to calculate elements of many arrays in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a question about array in ruby

I have an array which contains many elements (strings with uppercases and down case ) and i want to know how many element (how many string) in this array contains an uppercase letters :
i obtain many element but i dont know how to calculate them
thank you.

```
array.each do |arr|

  print arr.scan(/[A-Z]/)

end
```

Comment: Can you give some example input and the expected result?

Comment: [Enumerable#grep](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) could be used: `['foo', 'Foo', 'FoO'].grep(/\p{Lu}/).size`. When compared with @Sebastian's answer, however, it has two disadvantages: it requires two passes and creates a temporary array.  `grep` is a handy method in many situations, yet is often overlooked.

Answer (score 2):

Following your example, what you need is match? if you want a boolean result regarding if the element matches or not with an uppercase letter on it:

```
['foo', 'Foo', 'FoO'].each { |string| p string.match?(/[A-Z]/) }
# false
# true
# true
```

You can use count and pass a block to check if the current element returns true when evaluating if it contains uppercase characters. The result is the total of elements yielding a true value from the block:

```
['foo', 'Foo', 'FoO'].count { |string| /[[:upper:]]/ =~ string }
# 2
```

Answer (score 0):

So i did:

```
a = ["HellO", "hello", "World", "worlD"]
b = 0
a.each do |x|
  b += x.scan(/[A-Z]/).length
end
puts b   # Which equals 4 in this case
```

The problem I had in some of the answers above with my array.
For Cary's answer I get 3 which somehow missing one of the capital letters.
For Sebastian's answer I get 3 as well which is also somehow missing one of the capital letters.

My array has 2 capitals in the first string, 1 in the third and 1 in the fourth.

Of course the more normal ruby way would be with `b += x.scan(/[A-Z]/).count` instead of `.length` but it worked for me in irb.

Some sample output from my console of the three methods:

```
030 > a.grep(/\p{Lu}/).size
 => 3 
:031 > a.count {|string| /[[:upper:]]/ =~ string}
 => 3
:026 > a.each do |x|
:027 >     b += x.scan(/[A-Z]/).length
:028?>   end
 => ["HellO", "hello", "World", "worlD"] 
:029 > b
 => 4
```

It appears as if the two regex examples above just check for any capital in the string and count it as one so if you had multiple in the same string like my first `"HellO"` then it only counts as one:

```
:039 > ["HellO"].grep(/\p{Lu}/).size
 => 1 
:040 > ["HellO"].count {|string| /[[:upper:]]/ =~ string}
 => 1
```

Of course this may not matter to you but if the string is longer than one word it very well may:

```
2.5.3 :045 > a = ["Hello World"]
2.5.3 :047 > a.each do |x|
2.5.3 :048 >     b += x.scan(/[A-Z]/).count
2.5.3 :049?>   end
 => ["Hello World"] 
2.5.3 :050 > b
  => 2 
2.5.3 :051 > a.count {|string| /[[:upper:]]/ =~ string}
 => 1 
2.5.3 :052 > a.grep(/\p{Lu}/).size
 => 1
```

With two words in one string it you can see the difference.

Of course I am counting the total capital letters when you asked,

```
i want to know how many element (how many string) in this array contains an uppercase letters
```

In which case either of the other two answers above do beautifully :)